# How can we design android layout which are compatible to all mobile screens?

Tags: android

I have taken **layout-320dp,layout-360dp,layout-480dp,layout-600dp and layout-720dp** but still some of devices are not compatible to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to create all these layout files. Your app is compatible with all the mobile devices using  layout and layout-large but for tablets you need to use layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp for 7" and 10" screens. For more reference visit this link :-

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Hope this help you :)